# Android Layout - layouts of 3 textviews inside a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I searched and try a lot about my problem, but I haven't found a solution yet, also I tried whatever answer I was able to find on this site and much more, but I didn't find a proper solution.

My problem is simple, I have a Listview containing 3 textviews, and for each textview I'd like to set their layout parameters such as height and width.
Like this, more or less:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| Data1   |         Data2         | Data 3    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

My only requests are:
Data1 is small, it contains only a date in hh:mm format;
Data2 layout_width must be fixed at let's say 80sp and contains multiline text
Data3 is small like Data1, it only changes the Text-size.

My problem is that when I enter some long text in Data2, my TextView doesn't show it all and not rearrange the other layout parameters in respect of my Data2 text. I tried to set

```
layout_height="wrap_content"
layout_width="80sp"
```

but unfortunately it didn't work.
I tried all "wrap_content" and "match_parent" permutation, "singleLine='False'", "maxEms='15'", "scrolling" etc.. but none of them worked.

So there is a solution for that?
This is what I was thinking to achieve:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| Data1_0   |         Data2_0         | Data 3_0    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|           |        Data2_1          |             |
| Data1_1   |        Data2_1          |   Data3_1   |
|           |        Data2_1          |             |
|           |        Data2_1          |             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| .......
```

This is my code:

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

My Listview has a proper design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxEms="15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

P.s. width's of textview are all okay, it seems that only Data2 textview height set with "wrap_content" is not working well...
Hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance for your helps!

**EDIT:**
So far I could achieve this:

[image: screenshot of an example]

That is so great!
But ... for the sake of programming... and for beeing a little "finicky"... I'd like to align all columns of price on the right of the description. How could I do this?
The screenshot was taken from this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxEms="8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**SOLVED!**
Thanks guys for all of your efforts!
I am relatively new to Android, I learned so much ("sp" != "dp" !) , and I was able to solve my problem with the RelativeLayout's solution!
For the sake of "problem-solving" I'm posting what I used.
Once more, thanks to all of you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxEms="8"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing your data 2's text view to 80**dp** rather than sp. Whether it helps or not for things like width and height you are supposed to use dp. :)

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE Thank you for your answer! I was using "sp" because AStudio tells me that! It tells "_When setting text sizes, you should normally use sp,or "scale-independent pixels". This is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and the user's preference. There are cases where you might need to use dp [...] however that this means that the user's font size settings are not respected, so consider adjusting the layout itself to be more flexible._"

Comment: Android Studio tells you to set **TEXT SIZE** to sp. For any dimensions you are supposed to use **DP**. Remember sp is for font size and dp is for any dimensions. :) Hope that clears your doubt. AStudio points out the `textSize` parameter not your `layout_width` or `layout_height` parameter which should be set to dp. :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you are right. I was wrong, thank you for pointing it out for me :)

Comment: @pippo Try with my answer and let me know is it work for you or not.

Comment: @pippo Its ok :) Glad I could help

Comment: For avoid misunderstandings, I used this RelativeLayout configuration to my Listview definition, so my list is actually a RelativeLayout with 3 textviews... What I posted as a solution is my xml code for listview, not for activity main :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try Using `Relative Layout` with your code.**

`Replace this with your XML Code.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="80sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
        android:maxEms="15"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TEsting TEsting TEsting TEstingTEstingTEstingTEstingTEsting " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is `Screen Shot` How it Looks with Above XML.**

[image]

Comment: OP mentioned a list view. Consider putting this relative layout inside a scroll view too so it will  function a bit similarly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use set weight in your TextViews.
Here is an example:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/kuku1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/kuku2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/kuku3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I can read all my text! But unfortunately I can't fixed my Data2 to preferred width in such a way...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="text1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#c3c3c3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxEms="15"
        android:text="text2 long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#5555ff"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="text3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

In `ListView` it will take size of one `ListView` item.

Comment: Yeah, you are near to what i want! thank you for your answer! Still I'm not able to set up my Data2's width to 80sp, that is what I'd like to do...

Comment: In width params, as it was stated above, you should use "dp", "sp" is used only for text sizes. Setting weights instead of fixed size in dp units will give you much more flexibility.

Comment: okay, I'll give it a deeper try... I tried all the answer from all, but nothing was precisely as I wanted.. I'll let you know :)

Comment: Try it and put screenshots of result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope its useful.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaa"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:maxEms="10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="sample looooooooonnnnnnnnnggggggggg text"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="aaaa"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately my Data2 text isn't wrapped at all.. plus Data2 width should be at "80sp"

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. The theory is that you have first and third text boxes where max width can be predicted.

Textview1: set min, max widths since it's predictable size
Textview3: set min, max widths since only text size is changing
Textview4: width: wrapcontent, multi-line:true

Other option is consider using PercentRelativeLayout if you don't have a very strong reason to stick to ListView.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading about PercentRelativeLaoyut because I didn't know it before, maybe it will be my solution... Meanwhile, it is curious that I have set "width='wrap_content'" on my Data2 and "singleLine='true'" to give a try.. and it works like I'd like it to work with height! It's wrapping well just for "the width" all text I inserted! but for "height", it seems it's another deal... I wonder why is so much complicated what I want to do (I thought as it's a natural behavior of a textview make a carriage return when space is finished, create new line and display all contents!)

Answer (score 0):

Your only issue is text1's width which is fill_parent.Change it with wrap_content or some fixed size and your problem is automatically solved.